# Simple javascript onClick Text change

Tags: javascript

I am new to StackExchange. I have very basic question in JavaScript.

I have created simple JavaScript function changing the color of the text using `onClick` in that same function i want to change the last word

Here is the example

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>
    Sample Javascript
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function colorchange(myid)
    {
        x = document.getElementById('sample_text');
        x.style.color = "red";
        x.style.fontWeight = "bold";

        text = document.getElementById('sample_text1');

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sample_text" onClick="colorchange(1)">Welcome to <span onClick="colorchange(2)" id="sample_text1">Mahaweb</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me I want to change the span inner content with the same function.

Comment: Something like text.innerHTML="new word" http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: see my answer if it helped you accept that please ;)

Comment: use below of **text = document.getElementById('sample_text1');** add this code **if(myid==2){
       text.innerHTML="HELLO";
    }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function colorchange(myid)
    {
        x = document.getElementById('sample_text');
        x.style.color = "red";
        x.style.fontWeight = "bold";

        text = document.getElementById('sample_text1');
        if(myid==2){
           text.innerHTML="YOUR TEXT HERE";  
        }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>
    Sample Javascript
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function colorchange()
{
x = document.getElementById('sample_text');
x.style.color = "red";
x.style.fontWeight = "bold";

document.getElementById('sample_text1').innerHTML = "text";

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sample_text" onClick="colorchange()">Welcome to <span onClick="colorchange()" id="sample_text1">Mahaweb</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the span's inner text. As you have already selected the `span` (`var text`), try:

`text.innerHTML="desiredText";`

Comment: Hi Paris Nelson, thank you so much. One more small query which i forgot to mention in my question.

once I click the text it was changing but again if i click the same text it has to go back to the original text

Comment: Do you want it to alternate between the texts? If so simply create a boolean variable. Every time the span is clicked, reverse the value. Then use that to determine the value of the text.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">                                       var bool=true;
function colorchange()
{                                                                    
x = document.getElementById('sample_text');
x.style.color = "red";
x.style.fontWeight = "bold";
bool=!bool;                                                           if(bool==false)
   document.getElementById('sample_text1').innerHTML = "newtext";    else                         
   document.getElementById('sample_text1').innerHTML = "oldtext"; 
}

</script>

Comment: Hi paris is that possible to modify the question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing the property "innerHTML" of your text Element.

Something like:

```
text.innerHTML = "your_change";
```

But this is pretty basic stuff. Make sure to checkt out some documentations ;)

Answer (score -3):

I believe this is what you are after (I am using jQuery, a javascript library, which makes this sort of thing much easier)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sample_text').click(function(){
     $(this).find('span').css('color', 'red').css('font-weight', 'bold');
});

</script>
```